# Problem with Ajax Tabpanel selection

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0, tabpanel

I have a 2 tabpanels in my tabcontainer and both the panel has their own header text.
I have put the tabcontainer inside a table.

Above the table (OR tabcontainer) I have a label and what I am trying to do is ... changing the label text as per tab selection ... code below:

```
if(tabcontainer.activetabindex == 0)
{
 label1.text = tabpanel1.headertext;
}

 else {label1.text = tabpanel2.headertext;}
```

But this is not working ... even if I select the panel2 my label displays the same text as panel1 header text ... it's not changing as I want.

Am I doing anything wrong? Please help.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TabContainer changes active panel without postback, so your code doesn't fire.
You have to create javascript code and call it on tabchange in browser.

Comment: AHH!!! that make sense. Do, you have any code sample as to ... How can I do this in client side using JS. Thanks.